# What is the easiest way to run a part of a model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm dealing with Keras functional API. 
Specifically for my experiments, I'm using Keras resnet50 model obtained with:

```
model = resnet50.ResNet50(weights='imagenet')
```

Obviously, to get the final output of the network we need to feed a value to the placeholder `input_1`.

My question is, can I somehow start inferencing this graph from the `relu` layer which is depicted at the bottom of the picture below, provided that I feed a value of the appropriate dimensions into it?

I tried to achieve this with Keras `functions`. Something like:

```
self.inp = model.input
self.outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers]
self.functor = K.function([self.inp, K.learning_phase()], [self.outputs[6], self.outputs[17]])
```

But this approach will not work, because again to inference any output I need to feed value into tensor.

Is recreating graph from scratch my best option here?

Thanks

[image: The input of the network is input_1. The layer of interest is Relu at the bottom]

Comment: just curious how did you create I mean that image of the computation graph  ?

Comment: @mujjiga enjoy some great visualization tools :D https://lutzroeder.github.io/netron/

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you can just specify input and output nodes

```
base_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(weights='imagenet')
inference_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=base_model.get_layer('any_layer_name').output)
```

You can set the output to any layer name

Comment: That is looking extremely promising! Will try that out and mark as accepted if it works. Thanks